# Disable line wrapping for Spans in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

When adding Spans to a FormattedString in Xamarin Forms, [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15378) is present if the text in the Span is long enough to wrap onto a new line.

Is there a property I can set on the Span to prevent line wrapping?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a property I can set on the Span to prevent line wrapping?

If you only want to set on the Span to prevent line wrapping, you can add `LineBreakMode` property to Label:

```xml
<ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <Label FontSize="Large" LineBreakMode="NoWrap">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString x:Name="FormattedString">
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the effect:

[image]

But it still has that issue.